# How to add json array object as a single documents in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
[
 {
    "item_id":"62f5df71dabf3cd385c6beee",
    "qty":2,
    "price":500
 },
 {
    "item_id":"62f5df71dabf3cd385c6beer",
    "qty":4,
    "price":1500
 },
 {
    "item_id":"62f5df71dabf3cd385c6acdg",
    "qty":1,
    "price":5500
 }
]
```

I want to add the above JSON object array that comes as a request body into my database as a single documents. How should I do that using a mongoose query?

Comment: Can you edited and add the collection schema to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very generic. We do not know anything about your collection structure but let me give you an example.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB,
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        auth: {
            username: "user",
            password: "xxx"
        },
        authSource: "admin"
    });
mongoose.set('debug', true);

//defining schema
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    items: [],
    //other fields
});

//init schema
const Order = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);

//your data
const data = [
    {
       "item_id":"62f5df71dabf3cd385c6beee",
       "qty":2,
       "price":500
    },
    {
       "item_id":"62f5df71dabf3cd385c6beer",
       "qty":4,
       "price":1500
    },
    {
       "item_id":"62f5df71dabf3cd385c6acdg",
       "qty":1,
       "price":5500
    }
   ];

//building your object to insert
const orderObject = {
    items: data
};

(async () => {
    //insert order
    const order = await Order.create(orderObject);
    //the order will show a _id if added correctly
    console.log(order);
})();
```

Comment: I want to add the above data as a single documents. not as a single object. Could you help me.